# Found nil while referencing a firebase document : No optionals used?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with Firebase. When referencing a document and attempting to modify/add data, it crashes every single time. It gives me a Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.

I have tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it. I have printed the user email (which gives me a valid email address every single time). Chosenbackground also is defined. I don't know why it keeps crashing because I am not using an optional that is nil.

This is what I import :

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseDatabase
import GoogleSignIn
```

Here I define db :
`var db : Firestore!`

Here chosenBackground is set and the function is called :

```
@objc func lightBlueAndOrangeImageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("lightBlueAndOrangeTapped")
        // Your action
        selectedBackgroundLabel.text = "Light Blue and Orange Background is selected"
        chosenBackground = "lightBlueAndOrange"
        chosenBackgroundToFirebase()
    }
```

This is the function :

```
func chosenBackgroundToFirebase(){ //IN THIS FUNCTION IT CRASHES
        if let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
            print("\(userEmail)")
            print("\(chosenBackground)")
            let newDocRef = db.collection("customizeDatabase").document("\(userEmail)") //ERROR ON THIS LINE

            newDocRef.updateData([
                "background": "\(chosenBackground)"
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                    newDocRef.setData([
                        "background" : "\(self.chosenBackground)"
                    ])
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully updated")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to read and write the document. Thank you very much for helping out :) I am a pretty new developer still so all the help was greatly appreciated :) (although it is a pretty stupid bug).

Comment: What line is this on?

Comment: I added what line it is on :) It is in the chosenBackgroundToFirebase() function

Comment: Try `print(db)` before the line at which it crashes. If it is `nil`, then the problem is setting the `db` variable.

Comment: You are right. db is nil. How could I fix it (and make it non-nil)?

Comment: @RosalieW how you initial the `db` before you accessing you must be set the value

Comment: Firebase should have detailed tutorials on how to initialise the `Firestore`. You have declared `db`: `var db : Firestore!`, but you have not _set_ it. Do this by doing `db = /* How Firestore should be created */`. _EDIT: Well, technically you have set `db` to `nil`. But you need to set it to an actual value._

Comment: In other view controllers, I did the exact same thing and it did work

Comment: Looking at the Firebase documentation, they do the exact same thing : https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/1c340aceae7b80ceaadc6eee0c51dea0587798b2/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/ViewController.swift#L243-L254

Comment: @RosalieW nope! should not. can you share the link where seeing this

Comment: @RosalieW There must be something different, because this should _never_ work. You must have missed a line - use `Command + F` to search for `db =` in each of those working view controllers, or look at the variable definition. `var db : Firestore!` is not the same as `var db = Firestore()`.

Comment: You are right. It is defined in viewDidLoad(). I'll add that line of code and try it again. It now works! Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully at [the code](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/1c340aceae7b80ceaadc6eee0c51dea0587798b2/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/ViewController.swift#L33), `db` is set in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // [START setup]
    let settings = FirestoreSettings()

    Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
    // [END setup]
    db = Firestore.firestore()
}
```

The problem was that `db` was `nil` - and due to that, the variable was force unwrapped implicitly, and caused a crash as there was no value (AKA `nil`).